# Vectors, dot product

Tags: vector-spaces

It is given that $|\mathbf{a}|= \sqrt{3}$ and $|\mathbf{b}|= 1$.

$\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are non-parallel, and the angle between them is $\frac{5\pi}{7}$.

I've also found out from the first part that $|\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}|= \mathbf{1}$. By considering $(2 \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b}) \cdot (2 \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b})$, or otherwise, find the exact value of $|(2 \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{b})|$.

Comment: Use the distributive property.

Comment: What does $|\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}| = \mathbf{1}$ mean? $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}$ is already a scalar since it is an inner product. Therefore, the statement you wrote is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* 
$(2\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})\cdot (2\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})=4\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{a}\rangle+4\langle \mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\rangle+\langle \mathbf{b},\mathbf{b} \rangle$.